GPU time sharing on GKE
I'm trying to use GPU Time sharing from instructions here, however my workloads will not run on the time-sharing enabled nodes.
I have a node pool with GPU configuration, GPU sharing enabled with Time-sharing for strategy and "Max shared clients per GPU" as 48. The node(s) run fine but I'm unable to run workloads on them using the documented nodeSelector config for my workload, e.g.
nodeSelector:
  cloud.google.com/gke-accelerator: "nvidia-tesla-t4"
  cloud.google.com/gke-max-shared-clients-per-gpu: "48"
  cloud.google.com/gke-gpu-sharing-strategy: time-sharing

With this my pods get stuck in pending status with message x nodes didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector. If I remove the gke-max-shared-clients-per-gpu and gke-gpu-sharing-strategy key pairs, the pod schedules and runs fine.
When I check the kubernetes labels on the nodes in the gpu time sharing node pool, they do NOT include these labels and I can't add them manually because GCP prevents it.
Any suggestions?

You are getting error nodes didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector as labels are not matching, as you have mentioned you have checked the nodes and they do not include labels.
I have followed the same document you have mentioned and I have replicated the issue and I got the pods scheduled on the node.
Note: I have used standard cluster and autopilot deployment.
I have created a cluster as shown below:

As mentioned in the doc I have created a nodepool but it was not scheduling the pods in it. So I have deleted the default node pool and created a new node pool with using command:
gcloud container node-pools create gputimesharing \
    --region=us-west4-a \
    --cluster-version=latest \
    --machine-type=n1-standard-16 \
    --accelerator=type=nvidia-tesla-t4,count=1,gpu-sharing-strategy=time-sharing,max-shared-clients-per-gpu=12,gpu-driver-version=default

Then the nodes have used this node pool, then I have tried deploying the workload using below spec:
  nodeSelector:
    cloud.google.com/gke-accelerator: "nvidia-tesla-t4"
    cloud.google.com/gke-gpu-sharing-strategy: "time-sharing"
    cloud.google.com/gke-max-shared-clients-per-gpu: "12"

Checked the nodes have the labels: 
Then the pods are scheduled without any error.
Can you try this process and let me know if you are getting any errors, and verify the number of GPUs visible in your nodes as mentioned in the doc.

Thank you for your help! I was able to get gpu timesharing working by creating the node pool via gcloud CLI as you suggested. It appears there's some bug with accomplishing the same thing using console.
